# Can you use a limb that is constricting an enemy to make an attack on another enemy using the improved grab ability?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, monsters

I am running a boss fight with a kraken this week.

The Kraken has the constrict ability which allows it to do automatic constrict damage on a successful grapple check after it has grasped someone with it's tentacle.

The Kraken has the improved grab ability which states:

> If a creature with this special attack hits with a melee weapon (usually a claw or bite attack), it deals normal damage and attempts to start a grapple as a free action without provoking an attack of opportunity. No initial touch attack is required.
>
> Unless otherwise noted, improved grab works only against opponents at least one size category smaller than the creature. The creature has the option to conduct the grapple normally, or simply use the part of its body it used in the improved grab to hold the opponent. If it chooses to do the latter, it takes a -20 penalty on grapple checks, **but is not considered grappled itself**; the creature does not lose its Dexterity bonus to AC, still threatens an area, and **can use its remaining attacks against other opponents**.
>
> A successful hold does not deal any extra damage unless the creature also has the constrict special attack. If the creature does not constrict, each successful grapple check it makes during successive rounds automatically deals the damage indicated for the attack that established the hold. Otherwise, it deals constriction damage as well (the amount is given in the creature’s descriptive text).
>
> When a creature gets a hold after an improved grab attack, it pulls the opponent into its space. This act does not provoke attacks of opportunity. It can even move (possibly carrying away the opponent), provided it can drag the opponent’s weight.

Can it still use this constricting tentacle to make attacks against other players while it is grappling/constricting another player or does this tentacle only deal constrict damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The act of [constricting](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Constrict) makes a grapple check and while grappling you are allowed to attack/move that character on future actions but not others.

From the [wiki](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Kraken) a Kraken:
Krakens strike their opponents with their barbed tentacles, then grab and crush with their arms or drag victims into their huge jaws. An opponent can make sunder attempts against a kraken’s tentacles or arms as if they were weapons. A kraken’s tentacles have 20 hit points, and its arms have 10 hit points. **If a kraken is currently grappling a target with one tentacle or arm, it usually uses another limb to make its attack of opportunity against the sunder attempt.** Severing a kraken’s tentacle or arm deals damage to the kraken equal to half the limb’s full normal hit points. A kraken usually withdraws from combat if it loses both tentacles or three of its arms. A kraken regrows severed limbs in 1d10+10 days.

Also, since this is a Kraken, you have 1 other tentacle to attack with so....

http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Grapple

Comment: I realized I had not spelled out the Kraken has the improved grab ability, I have updated